# MS Visual Source Safe 6.0

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have a VC++ 6.0 Project running on Windows NT workstation. We want to bring this project under MS Visual source safe version control system. I have found that VSS 6.0 is the right version for the older project.

The server is running on Windows 2003 (32 bit). I would like to get clear idea on the below questions before proceed with VSS 6.0 installation.

1. suggest a plugin for VC++ 6.0 so i can directly checkin/checkout the files from the studio.
2. any problem running client on NT and server on win 2003.
3. good place to look for tutorials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SourceSafe comes with a MSSCCI plugin which supports integration with VC++ 6.0. [This article](http://www.codepool.biz/version-control/sourcesafe/integrating-sourcesafe-vss-with-visual-c-60.html) might help you. When using VSS 6.0, I recommend you apply VS6SP6.

Meanwhile, VSS is a bit old and deesn't work well for remote teams. You might want to try some other source control tools and see which fits your needs better.

Comment: I'd put it more strongly than that. Visual Source Safe is the worst piece of software I've ever encountered and I would recommend avoiding it at almost any cost, it will cause you untold pain. You can use something modern and capable like git instead without needing the visual studio integration at all. See http://www.git-scm.com/